# How to create a fading effect on the border of an object, with illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, transparency, stroke

Imagine I have a black disc. I would like to create a gradient around the disc, whose value is white 100% opacity on the border of the disc and white 0% opacity at the end of the gradient.

Now, replace the disc with any other object : I want to do something similar.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you mean an outer glow?

Comment: Yes, the effect is quite good. Do you know if there would be other way to do it ?

Comment: Other than what?

Comment: Other than with the "outer glow" method. I am totally satisfied by the result and so I wanted to know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: You can try abusing the drop shadow tool or build an offset shape with a gradient or gradient mesh. There is always another way. But it's really just experimenting.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to fade your object into another colour or background, you can use the Feather tool.

Go to Effect > Stylize > Feather and then play around with the distance, opacity and transparency until you're happy with the result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want add outer-glow to object, goto menu **Effect** » **Stylize** » **Outer Glow**.
it will display a popup. Now change the value.[image]